# disable broken auto-downloaded website fonts in SeaMonkey/Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, anti-aliasing, seamonkey

I've set up Windows 7 for high performance; and now some corporate web-sites have very weird-looking fonts.

After using archive.is for [one such page](http://www.online.net/en/dedicated-server/dedicated-server-overview-start) for an unrelated cause, I noticed in its progress report that something along the lines of a web-font being mentioned as downloading.

And yet the [resulting page on archive.is](http://archive.is/NIBUW%0A) doesn't have any weird-looking fonts, probably because they didn't save any such fonts in the end.

**Looks like most of these web fonts are not designed to be usable without anti-aliasing in place.  How do I disable such broken web-fonts from being used in my SeaMonkey?**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to disable the broken ones, or if they're all broken, but to disable all of the downloadable fonts, toggle **`gfx.downloadable_fonts.enabled`** from **true** to **false**.

Warning:  this seems to break github somewhat, because they display all of their icons through the characters of their downloadable fonts.